# Returning an object from Future<List> in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm struggle on parsing Future to object. I want to retrieve the `User` data from `Future<List<User>>` to `User` object. I can get the User data, but its still inside `Future`.

```dart
Future<List<User>> getDataUser(String name_,int id_) async{
    var datajson=await Network.getData("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users?username=$name_&id=$id_");
    final response=jsonDecode(datajson);
    List<User> fuser=response.map((r)=>User.fromJson(r)).toList();
    User user_=fuser.single;
    print('response: '+user_.name);
    return fuser;
}
```

EDIT: `Network.getData` is a `Future<dynamic>`

When I call `activeUser()`, I want it to return an object (`User`).

```dart
User activeUser(Future<List<User>> fuser){
    List<User> user=fuser as List<User>;
    print('user: '+user.single.username);
    return user.single;
}
```

I always get this kind of `error : type 'Future<List<User>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<User>'`
I'm avoiding using *builder*(`FutureBuilder` or `ListView.Builder` or else) because I'm not going to make a list. It just a single map. I want that `Future<List<User>>` is returning a `User` object. The REST API I use, returning a list, not an object

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  }
]
```

- Notice the rectangle bracket, its a list with one json map.

Comment: add await when You call your function: ```await activeUser()```

Comment: still didn't work, it show error : `Unhandled Exception: type 'Future<List<User>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<User>' in type cast`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out.

I created a *class* `ListUser` to store the list that returned from a `Future`

```dart
class ListUser{
  final List<User> oneuser;

  DaftarUser({this.oneuser});

  factory ListUser.fromJson(List<dynamic> jsonuser){
    List userone=new List();
    userone=jsonuser.map((p)=>User.fromJson(p)).toList();

    return new ListUser(
      oneuser:userone
    );
  }
}
```

Then I call the class above to `Future<List<User>>`

```dart
Future<List<User>> getDataUser(String name_,int id_) async{
    var datajson=await Network.getData("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users?username=$name_&id=$id_");
    final response=jsonDecode(datajson);
    List<User> fuser=ListUser.fromJson(datajson).oneuser;
    // User user_=fuser.single;
    // print('response: '+user_.name);
    // those two line above are for seeing the value only, not too important
    return fuser;
}
```

The Function above will return a `List<User>`, so that I can change the `activeUser` function, like this:

```dart
User activeUser(List<User> fuser){
    User u=fuser.single;
    return u;
}
```

Now I can call that `activeUser` anywhere I need it.

BTW, thanks for the help above. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var fName;
...

getDataUser(name, id).then((fuser){
    print('user: '+ fuser.single.username);
    this.fName = fuser.single;});
```

Comment: doesn't work, I've add return to *fName*, but I'm still getting `*null*`

Comment: Make a class variable for fName and change fName to this.fName. I've edited my answer